# In Delphi, how can I force tListView to always show selected row, even when not focused.

Tags: delphi, tlistview

The selected row of a tListView appears blue, but only when the control has focus.  I'd like the selected row to always be displayed, whether the control has focus or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the [`HideSelection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TCustomListView.HideSelection) property to `False`.

> Determines whether the list view gives a visual indication of which item is selected when focus shifts to another control.
>
> Set **HideSelection** to false to provide visual feedback of the selected item in the list even when the list view does not have focus. Set **HideSelection** to true to show the selection only when the list view has focus. **HideSelection** does not affect the actual value of the selection, only the visual indication. Always setting **HideSelection** to false can make forms with many list views look too busy.

Comment: David, just a word of ... um, AWE!  How in the world do you know so much? :-)  I'm sure the rest of the Delphi community here on SO join me in thanking you, Serg, Ken, Remy, mjn, Marjan, GameCat and countless others (forgive me for not enumerating them all) for the enormous amount of help you all. It means A LOT to us all and makes a HUGE difference.  (Yes, I know this isn't an answer to the question, so I'm in the line of fire for negative votes. But sometimes, a guy has to break the rules to say "Thanks" where thanks is due ... to all of you!)

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I appreciate that a lot, and I'm sure all the others you mentioned and those that you forgot to mention appreciate it too. You've made me embarrassed now! That's an achievement in itself!  ;-)